# REACT nav bar requires two clicks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigation, navbar, nav

### Summary

When a user clicks the hamburger icon `className='.landing-page-hamburger'` it takes two clicks to toggle the navigation `className='landing-page-nav-links'` and I can't figure out why.

The display value for `.landing-page-nav-links` is set to `none` by default in the CSS.

### Problem

Navigation bar is requiring two clicks to toggle the `display` value

### Expected Result

Would expect to only need one click

### LandingPage.js

```
import React from 'react';

const LandingPage = () => {  
  const toggleNav = () => {
    const navLinks = document.querySelector('.landing-page-nav-links');

    if (navLinks.style.display === 'none') {
      navLinks.style.display = 'initial';
    } else {
      navLinks.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }

  return (
    <nav className='landing-page-nav'>
      <h1 className='take-notes-logo'>Take Notes</h1>
      <span className='landing-page-hamburger' onClick={() => toggleNav()}>☰</span>
      <ul className='landing-page-nav-links'>
        <li>Sign Up</li>
        <li>Log In</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default LandingPage;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your external CSS is not setting a `style` property on your element.  The first click sets it to `none` because it isn't there at all.  Your second click will now work as expected.

To fix this, either set the style of `.landing-page-hamburger` inline, or just toggle classes and let your external CSS handle it.

**EDIT:**  The OP asks an excellent question. The `.style` property refers to the element's [CSSStyleDeclaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) object.  This is a [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) interface that you are directly manipulating.  Notice, when you inspect an element in your console, the CSSStyleDeclaration does not necessarily match what you see in the CSS you get from the style sheet.  Also, note that the properties are JS-style camelCase; this illustrates that this is not a direct mapping, yet they both effect the element.

So my initial description of the property being not there at all isn't accurate.  It's there, and it's set to the empty string, which is the default CSSStyleDeclaration.  So you set it to "none" on the second click and all goes well from there.  Your initial CSS declaration is working correctly, but not figuring into your `if` statement because it's not referring to the same thing.  Same effect, but you're interfacing with your element in a different way.

Comment: Thanks for this. I just went the route of inline styling as it was easier for me. Could you please explain why there is no `style` property as this should work with normal JavaScript in a typical website (HTML, CSS, JS) correct?

Comment: I had to read those MDN links to really get it myself.  I learned something here too. :) Keep asking great questions!